# Custom ValueConvertor to display enum value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a BasisOfFee property that is mapped to an BasisOfFeeType enum.

How can I ensure that when I query the web api endpoint, it returns a "Display" data annotation of the enum value instead of the enum value itself?

I checked the different [Microsoft provided valueType convertors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) and I could not find a HashSet to value type convertor.

```
public class ProductSvc
{
  public BasisOfFeeType BasisOfFee{get;set}
}
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public enum BasisOfFeeType
{
  [Display(Name="Male Person")]
  Male:1,
  [Display(Name="Female Person")]
  Female:2
}
public class ProductSvcEntityConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductSvc>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductSvc> builder)
  {
    builder.Property().HasColumnName("basis_of_fee").HasConversion(new 
    EnumToNumberConvertor<BasisOfFeeType, byte>());
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try ToString()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by changing BasisOfFeeType

```
using System.RunTime.Serialization;
public enum BasisOfFeeType
{
  [EnumMember(Value="Male Person")]
  Male:1,
  [EnumMember(Value="Female Person")]
  Female:2
}
```

Comment: it seems like this doesn't work anymore in EF Core 6